# fetching listview using json parsor in fragment

Tags: android, json, xml, android-fragments

settings Fragment

```
package com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;

import com.sample.mpassbook.httpconnection.Httpmanager;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
 * Created by abhil on 22/07/15.
 */
public class Settingsfragment extends Fragment {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url="https://fierce-tundra-4082.herokuapp.com/transactions/?msisdn=456&account=123&from_date=2015-07-10&format=json";
    public static final String TAG_content = "content";
    public static final String TAG_bankid = "bank_id";
    public static final String TAG_status = "details";
    public static final String TAG_Date = "date";
    public static final String TAG_cval = "amount";
    //    public static final String TAG_dval = "debit_val";
    public static final String TAG_bal = "balance";
    JSONArray content = null;

    public Settingsfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);


        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new getlist().execute();
    }
    private class getlist extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
        Httpmanager jParser = new Httpmanager();
        private JSONObject json;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }
        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

            // Getting JSON from URL
            String json = jParser.makeServiceCall(url, Httpmanager.get);
           oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                content = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_content);


                for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject c = content.getJSONObject(i);

                    String bank_id = c.getString(TAG_bankid);
                    String details = c.getString(TAG_status);
                    String date = c.getString(TAG_Date);
                    String amount = c.getString(TAG_cval);
                    String balance = c.getString(TAG_bal);


                    HashMap<String, String> contents = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    contents.put(TAG_bankid, "TRANSACTION ID : " + bank_id);
                    contents.put(TAG_status, "" + details);
                    contents.put(TAG_Date, "" + date);
                    contents.put(TAG_cval, "" + amount);
                    oslist.add(contents);
                    list = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.list_item);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



                    return null;
                }
                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute (JSONObject json){
                    pDialog.dismiss();
       ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist,                     R.layout.item, new String[]{TAG_bankid, TAG_status, TAG_Date, TAG_cval},
       new int[]{R.id.bankid, R.id.status, R.id.date, R.id.cval});
                        list.setAdapter(adapter);



                }
            }

}
```

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.TransactionFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"/>

    </LinearLayout>
    <!--<TextView-->
        <!--android:id="@+id/label"-->
        <!--android:layout_alignParentTop="true"-->
        <!--android:layout_marginTop="100dp"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="fill_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
        <!--android:gravity="center_horizontal"-->
        <!--android:textSize="45dp"-->
        <!--android:text="HOME"-->
        <!--android:textStyle="bold"/>-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/item">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/bankid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:text="bankid"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/status"
        android:layout_width="67dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:text="status"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bankid"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dval"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textColor="#43bd00"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_above="@+id/date"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bankid"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bankid" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cval"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bankid"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/bankid"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/bankid" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="71dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:text="date"
        android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_below="@+id/status"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

i had debugged the code am getting each and every parsing but the error is on line 120 in settings fragment where my list is not appending to items. kindly give suggestions am new to android. It will help me a lot. Please don't take it as a negative question. Ur suggestions will be valuable for me.

Logcat messeage

```
07-27 10:29:30.634    2273-2289/com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d, PID: 2273
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.Settingsfragment$getlist.doInBackground(Settingsfragment.java:121)
            at com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.Settingsfragment$getlist.doInBackground(Settingsfragment.java:78)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-27 10:29:30.671    2273-2285/com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d I/art﹕ Background sticky concurrent mark sweep GC freed 6004(337KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 18% free, 1712KB/2MB, paused 7.003ms total 27.902ms
07-27 10:29:36.604    2273-2273/com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-27 10:29:36.626    2273-2273/com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d E/WindowManager﹕ android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{22ccd5ff V.E..... R......D 0,0-1026,348} that was originally added here
            at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:363)
            at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:261)
            at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:69)
            at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
            at com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.Settingsfragment$getlist.onPreExecute(Settingsfragment.java:88)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:587)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:535)
            at com.sample.mpassbook.mpassbook_d.Settingsfragment.onActivityCreated(Settingsfragment.java:76)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:1797)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:979)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1138)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:740)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1501)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:551)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1220)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5953)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

Comment: first of all take out `setAdapter()` piece of code from the `for` loop. And indicate 120 line number.

Comment: Your way of asking question was very polite.. You can also mention what exactly the error was, and pointing which one is `line 120` will also help.

Comment: Yes move that code out of the loop.. fill the `ArrayList` with data..once data id fiiled call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: that i've tried and added in onpostexecutive still am getting the same error on line 133 @SpringBreaker

Comment: line 120 is istAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, R.layout.item, new String[]{TAG_bankid, TAG_status, TAG_Date, TAG_cval},
                            new int[]{R.id.bankid, R.id.status, R.id.date, R.id.cval});                      @Darpan

Comment: i've already changed the code from for loop and added in onpostexecutive will update the code in question but the now the error is on line 133 same code. @bGorle

Comment: Yes, it is null because of your null 'list' because you have `android:id="@android:id/list"`  as Spring suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should not do any UI operation on the background thread.Also you are making wrong  `ListView` declaration in the xml file. Change to following,

```
<ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"/>
```

Then change your `Fragment` code  like below,

```
public class Settingsfragment extends Fragment {
    ListView list;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> oslist;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private static String url="https://fierce-tundra-4082.herokuapp.com/transactions/?msisdn=456&account=123&from_date=2015-07-10&format=json";
    public static final String TAG_content = "content";
    public static final String TAG_bankid = "bank_id";
    public static final String TAG_status = "details";
    public static final String TAG_Date = "date";
    public static final String TAG_cval = "amount";
    //    public static final String TAG_dval = "debit_val";
    public static final String TAG_bal = "balance";
    JSONArray content = null;

    public Settingsfragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.settings, container, false);

 list = (ListView) rootView .findViewById(R.id.list_item);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new getlist().execute();
    }
     private class getlist extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
                Httpmanager jParser = new Httpmanager();
                private JSONObject json;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                    pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                    pDialog.show();
                }
                @Override
                protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

                    // Getting JSON from URL
                    String json = jParser.makeServiceCall(url, Httpmanager.get);
                   oslist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
                        content = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_content);


                        for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = content.getJSONObject(i);

                            String bank_id = c.getString(TAG_bankid);
                            String details = c.getString(TAG_status);
                            String date = c.getString(TAG_Date);
                            String amount = c.getString(TAG_cval);
                            String balance = c.getString(TAG_bal);


                            HashMap<String, String> contents = new HashMap<String, String>();

                            contents.put(TAG_bankid, "TRANSACTION ID : " + bank_id);
                            contents.put(TAG_status, "" + details);
                            contents.put(TAG_Date, "" + date);
                            contents.put(TAG_cval, "" + amount);
                            oslist.add(contents);

                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }



                            return null;
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected void onPostExecute (JSONObject json){
                            pDialog.dismiss();


                            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getActivity(), oslist, R.layout.item, new String[]{TAG_bankid, TAG_status, TAG_Date, TAG_cval},
                                    new int[]{R.id.bankid, R.id.status, R.id.date, R.id.cval});
                            list.setAdapter(adapter);

                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Thankyou it worked. Expecting suggestions and helps in future... onceagain thankyou verymuch

Comment: it needs reputation. @bGorle